# vtiger - creating permanent milestone on every new project

Tags: vtiger

I'm trying to auto create certain milestones for each new project created.

the goal of this is enabling a set of permanent milestones for each project.

I'm a newbie in vTiger and would appreciate any help you can extend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Project Plan with a Project Milestone connected and when you want to create a new project you can duplicate it. 
It will duplicate the Project and the elements related

Comment: Doing this you don't have to touch any row of code, otherwise in the ProjectPlan.php on save_module() you have to generate a ProjectMilestone record with your parameter.